# Authentication error when connecting to mysql database using node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, database-connection

what's up

I have a problem when I connect to a Mysql database.
The version of mysql I use is 5.0.95.
And the version of mysql2 is 3.6.5

The error in question is: Error: Server requests authentication using unknown plugin . See TODO: add plugins doco here on how to configure or author authentication plugins.

Connection string:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

const connection = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'bancp',
    ssl: false
});

module.exports = connection;
```

Query used:

```
const connection = require('./connection');

const allClientes = async () => {
    const[query] = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM Clientes LIMIT 100');
}; 

module.exports = allClientes;
```

All the solutions involve changing the user's authentication mode, but this solution doesn't work for me because I'm working with a production database, and it's not legal to change the authentication used.

Thank you all, and sorry if I'm a bit confused, my English isn't great.

I've tried looking on various websites, and I've even read several of the questions here, but at no point have I found a solution other than this one:
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';